# How to show that in the space X=Q with the usual absolute value metric, the whole space is of first category in X

Tags: baire-category

I know that the union of all singleton sets {q} with q a rational is countable so the issue I'm having is showing that {q} is nowhere dense in X? I know this is true when X=R but having trouble when X=Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every open set in the metric space $\Bbb Q$ (with the usual Euclidean absolute value metric) is meagre, i.e., first category in $\Bbb Q$; in fact every subset of $\Bbb Q$ is meagre in $\Bbb Q$, because every subset of $\Bbb Q$ is countable, and $\{x\}$ is a closed, nowhere dense subset of $\Bbb Q$ for each $x\in\Bbb Q$. Hence $\mathbb{Q}$ is of first category in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: How do you know that {x} is a nowhere dense subset of Q? I understand that if {x} is closed then it is its own closure so I guess the question I'm asking is how do you know that the interior of {x} is empty.

Comment: I know it from several answers at MSE, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240060/what-is-the-interior-of-a-single-point-in-a-metric-space?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235349/what-is-the-interior-of-a-singleton).